# scene is unreachable due to a lack of entry points.. no identifier for runtime access?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, xcode6

This question has been asked & addressed before but i haven't found a solution that fixes my issue. why am i getting this "scene is unreachable due to a lack of entry points and does not have an identifier for runtime access via - instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier" error? when i run the app, after the launching image, it just turns black & the debugger has the following message:

[image]

my default TableViewController (which is my 1st) is instantiated with the following code within:

```
import UIKit

class FirstTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return 21
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell


        return cell
    }

}
```

and my following two tableViewControllers are also instantiated. what seems to be the issue?

Comment: I guess you have another Scene in your Storyboard that is not accessed via a segue and also doesn't have an identifier set. So connect it with a segue or set a Storyboard ID in the Identity Inspector. With the ID you can instantiate the ViewController using instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier.

Answer (score 0):

In your storyboard, make sure that your initial View Controller has an arrow pointing into it. If it does not, check "initial view controller" in the inspector window for that View Controller.

The application can't find the initial View Controller, that's all its complaining for.

Comment: yes this works, the app runs accordingly, however the error is still present. why is that?